# How can I automate rescheduling overdue daily tasks?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, elisp-macros

I have a number of "daily" tasks which repeat daily. If I forget to mark each task as DONE, it is removed from the timeline, and appears as an overdue item at the top of the agenda. For example, I forgot to turn off the hot water the last three days, so this task does not appear at its previously scheduled time (23:45), but instead appears at the top, because it's overdue.

```
  repeating:  Sched.3x:  TODO Turn off hot water           :daily:                                                                                
               8:00...... ----------------
              10:00...... ----------------
              12:00...... ----------------
              14:00...... ----------------
              16:00...... ----------------
              16:05...... now - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
  repeating:  17:30-18:30 Scheduled:  TODO Go for a walk   :daily:                                                          
              18:00...... ----------------
              20:00...... ----------------
```

Original todo tasks (today's date is `2022-05-26`):

```
* TODO Go for a walk :daily:
SCHEDULED: <2022-05-26 Thu 17:30-18:30 .+1d>
:PROPERTIES:
:LAST_REPEAT: [2022-05-25 Sat 18:34]
:Effort:   01:00
:END:

* TODO Turn off hot water :daily:
SCHEDULED: <2022-05-23 Mon 23:45-23:46 .+1d>
:PROPERTIES:
:LAST_REPEAT: [2022-05-22 Mon 23:37]
:Effort:   00:01
:END:
```

What I want is for any uncompleted daily task to be automatically rescheduled to the same time again today (23:45). I don't care if I'm overdue turning off the hot water from yesterday - I just want to remember to turn if off at the right time again today.

I've had a go at writing a method to do this:

```lisp
(defun org-reset-daily ()
  "Reschedule all old tasks tagged as daily in the agenda to today"
  (interactive)
  (org-map-entries
   (org-agenda-schedule nil "+0d")
   (format-time-string "daily+SCHEDULED<\"<%Y-%m-%d>\"") 'agenda))

(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook
          (lambda () (define-key org-agenda-mode-map "r" #'org-reset-daily)))
```

Here the string "daily+SCHEDULED<"<%Y-%m-%d>"" matches entries which are tagged as "daily" and scheduled for a time before the given date (today).

However, there are two problems:

1. For some reason when I run it in agenda mode, it only applies to the entry at point instead of all entries which match.
2. Rescheduling with the time delta "+0d" strips the time range from the schedule date (e.g. "23:45-23:46 ").

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Without a minimal working example with sample org-mode raw data to create a proposed solution, it is difficult to write up an answer.  The org-agenda output that is extracted from the raw data (which is missing) is insufficient.  There is presently no way to know for sure whether a habit entry is different than a regular entry, and whether we are dealing with deadline or scheduled, or both, and whether a time-span is mission critical.

Comment: @lawlist Apologies, have added the todo's to the question also.

Comment: @lawlist Is that what you were looking for, or is additional information required?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the information you have provided is now sufficient for someone to write-up an answer.  It is just a matter of someone taking the initiative to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57829278/6743243) which solves this problem using a custom agenda bulk action. The following should be added to config.el:

```lisp
;; Add bulk action shortcut to reschedule task to today, while preserving schedule time
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-bulk-custom-functions '(?D (lambda () (call-interactively 'org-agenda-date-later))))
```